# How to filter Symfony easyadmin Menu per user?

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, yaml, symfony2-easyadmin

I have a simple menu that looks like the following

```
easy_admin:
design:
    menu:
        - { entity: 'Entity2',icon: 'database' }
        - { entity: 'Entity3',icon: 'sitemap' }
        - { entity: 'Entity4',icon: 'window-restore'}
        - { entity: 'Entity5', icon: 'pencil'  }
        - { entity: 'Entity6',icon: 'address-book' }
        - { entity: 'Entity7',icon: 'cog' }
        - { entity: 'Entity8',icon: 'child' }
```

what i want to do is to show each menu item according to the logged in username, for example Entity2 to appear only if the logged in username is "admin".

also how to write if statement in .yml files ?!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just a little clarification, this is now something straightforward to do with EasyAdmin3 because you have access to services when building the main menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write if in .yml files.
There is no easy solution for this problem.

You could implement the solution given by javiereguiluz and rubengc in this github issue : https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/831.